# How to display the close button in red color

Tags: c#-4.0, razor, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

```
Html.Telerik().Window()
```

By default, window is displaying the **close - cross symbol** button in light blue color. I want the **close - cross symbol** button to be display in the red color.

Answer (score 0):

You can define style rule:

```
.t-window-actions .t-close { background-position:0px -288px; }
```